# Separate scope variablesin angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one scope variables for four elements in div. When I change the variable it affects all the four elements within which it is included. I am beginner in angular js and can't handle it alone.

Here is an example to explain better:

JS:

```
/* controller-home.js ********************************************************/
app.controller("homeController", function($scope, $http, $state) {
    $scope.heading = "SWITCHES";
    $scope.button1 = "Хол"
    $scope.button2 = "Кухня"
    $scope.button3 = "Баня"
    $scope.button4 = "Балкон"
    $scope.imageSrc = "LitLamp.png";


    $scope.onOf = function() {
        console.log("Switched");
        if ($scope.imageSrc === "LitLamp.png") {
            $scope.imageSrc = "NotLit.png";
        }


    }
})
```

The HTML:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <h1 >SWITCHES</h1>
    <div ng-controller="homeController">

        <div style="display:inline-block;">
            <button ng-click="onOf()" class="homeSwitchButton">{{button1}}</button>
            <img class="homeButtonImage" src="{{imageSrc}}" alt="Lamp" >
        </div>

        <div style="display:inline-block;">
            <button ng-click="onOf()" class="homeSwitchButton">{{button2}}</button>
            <img class="homeButtonImage" src="{{imageSrc}}" alt="Lamp" >
        </div>

        <div style="display:inline-block;">
            <button ng-click="onOf()" class="homeSwitchButton">{{button3}}</button>
            <img class="homeButtonImage" src="{{imageSrc}}" alt="Lamp" >
        </div>

        <div style="display:inline-block;">
            <button ng-click="onOf()" class="homeSwitchButton">{{button4}}</button>
            <img class="homeButtonImage" src="{{imageSrc}}" alt="Lamp" >
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I hit one of the four buttons, all the images change. How to group image with button, or when I hit the first button only the image below it to change and the rest three to remain unchanged?

Comment: Don't share the model (`imageSrc`) between the buttons, if you want to change the `imageSrc` by button, you need to keep a different model for each button.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is because you are using the same variable `imageSrc` for all image. What you can do here is create an object for each image.

```
$scope.images = {
  button1: 'source.png',
  button2: 'source.png',
  button3: 'source.png',
  button4: 'source.png'
}
```

In the `onOf` method you can pass the name of the button you are changing

```
$scope.onOf = function(buttonName) {
  if ($scope.images[buttonName] === 'bla.png') {
    $scope.images[buttonName] = 'yay.png';
  }
}
```

And in the html you set the images calling each property and passing the name of the button as argument on `onOf`

```
<div style="display:inline-block;">
   <button ng-click="onOf('button1')" class="homeSwitchButton">{{button1}}</button>
   <img class="homeButtonImage" src="{{images.button1}}" alt="Lamp" >
</div>
```

**Better approach**: You can put the buttons as an array and use `ng-repeat`

```
$scope.buttons = [{ name: 'bla', image: 'yay.png'}]

$scope.onOf = function(button) {
  if (button.image === 'yay') {
    ...
  }
}
```

And in the html

```
<div ng-repeat="button in buttons" style="display:inline-block;">
   <button ng-click="onOf(button)" class="homeSwitchButton">{{button.name}}</button>
   <img class="homeButtonImage" src="{{button.image}}" alt="Lamp" >
</div>
```